# Using a component containing other components within a router-view in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vue-router

I am trying to build a layout using single-file components in Vue.js, with dynamic population and URLs using Vue-router. (I'm using the webpack template via vue-cli as well.)

It works as expected for my app.vue file-- containing the nav, sidebar, page head, and `<router-view>`-- and the `<router-view>` content appeared as expected when the correct `<router-link>` is clicked... until I tried to add subcomponents to the add-load component being called to the `<router-view>`. Now, nothing appears at all, despite not throwing any errors.

Admittedly, I am not basing my structure on any examples, as I couldn't really find any doing it the way I was hoping to. I wanted to use nested components by calling them like custom elements-- I think this makes the code much easier to read and maintain. I'm not entirely sure how to structure it otherwise, to be honest. Using multiple `<router-view>s` as siblings to each other seems counterintuitive to me.

I've tried a variety of combinations of how and where to import and call the components, and nothing has worked. The only way I can get any content to load is if I only call a single component for `path: '/add-load'`. Is it just impossible to use multiple components outside of your base app.vue? I find that hard to believe. Here's what I started with.

From my index.js:

```
import AddLoad from '@/components/AddLoad'
import AddLoad from '@/components/ProgressSteps'
import Stops from '@/components/Stops'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      components: { 
        Sidebar,
        TopNav,
        MobNav,
        PageHead
            }
    },
    {
      path: '/add-load',
      components: {
        AddLoad, 
        ProgressSteps}
    }
  ]
})
```

From my App.vue file (the multiple component behavior that I'd like to mimic is shown here):

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <Sidebar/>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <TopNav/>
        <MobNav/>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <PageHead/>
          <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Sidebar from '@/components/Sidebar'
import TopNav from '@/components/TopNav'
import MobNav from '@/components/MobNav'
import PageHead from '@/components/PageHead'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Sidebar,
    TopNav,
    MobNav,
    PageHead
  }
}
</script>
```

From my AddLoad.vue file:

```
<template>
  <div class="add-load">
    <div class="content-container container-slim">
        <progress-steps/>
        <router-link to="#stops">Stops</router-link>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
import ProgressSteps from '@/components/ProgressSteps'

export default {
  name: 'AddLoad',
  component: ProgressSteps
}
</script>
```

Here is a link to a codesandbox, so you can see the full functionality. https://codesandbox.io/s/7k520xk0yq

Comment: I'm having difficulty parsing your question. Are you saying adding progress-steps to AddLoad seems to be the root of the problem - or that adding a router-view int here is an issue?

Comment: You'll get better responses if you can create a [minimal, verifiable, and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue. What you've shared wouldn't compile (hyphens aren't allowed in variable names).

Comment: Apologies-- I am saying that adding progress-steps to AddLoad seems to be the root of the problem. With only "AddLoad" in the index.js file, the html content of that template loads (even though progress-steps does not); but when I add progress-load to the index.js, no content loads.

Comment: As thanksd mentioned above, you can't use hyphen to name variable. Use CamelCase instead: 
```import AddLoad from '@/components/AddLoad'
import ProgressSteps from '@/components/ProgressSteps'
import Stops from '@/components/Stops'
```

Comment: Ah see what thanksd mentioned - the hyphen may be an issue.

Comment: Embarrassingly, that isn't in my original file structure. I fixed it in the question.

Comment: `components: { ProgressSteps }`, not `component: ProgressSteps` if you're trying to use the `<progress-steps/>` component tag in your `AddLoad.vue` file.

Comment: Curious-- that's what I thought the problem was originally, based on other questions I've read, but it's having no effect whatsoever on my result, as seen in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nj08n8k3l

Comment: So I've tried removing ProgressSteps from your online demo and I can't seem to get it work. Can you maybe show a "before" sandbox too - ie right before it breaks?

Comment: ... I'm an idiot, apparently. I guess I missed a combination of fixes-- if I use  `component: AddLoad` in the index.js file, and `components: {ProgressSteps}` in the AddLoad.vue file, it works. Thank you both!

Comment: But here's the working version, in case anyone is curious: https://codesandbox.io/s/963x6l6vw

Comment: Is this an intended situation? 

    import AddLoad from '@/components/AddLoad'
    import AddLoad from '@/components/ProgressSteps'

Comment: So glad you got it!